# Correlation Matrix using Matrix Algebra, not the Same as Result from Excel

Tags: matrices, correlation

I am attempting to verify a calculation found at another question on this site. 
The formula is said to provide a correlation matrix using

q = D<sup>-1</sup>ED<sup>-1</sup>

where q is the correlation matrix;

E is the covariance matrix obtained from A<sup>T</sup>A (where A is the original data matrix and A<sup>T</sup> is the transpose of A. (The source uses a capital sigma instead of E, but I don't know how to insert that character here)

D is the square root of each diagonal value in E, and D<sup>-1</sup> is the inverse of D. 
D<sup>-1</sup> must be a square matrix with values in the diagonal, but all others set to zero.

Beginning with my original data, I used Excel to create correlation matrix #1.  Then, using this method and Excel, I calculated correlation matrix #2.  The two are not the same. The Excel calculations use MMULT(Array1, Array2) for multiplication, and MINVERSE(Array) to obtain an inverse.  I have checked these two functions and they work properly. There are too many steps in the Excel sheet to try to include them here.

Checking around the internet I have not yet found as clear description as that at the link on this site, and yet I am unable to verify the calculations.

I must be missing something on how q is found, and look forward to suggestions on how to do this.

The other question I referenced is at  [Correlation matrix from Covariance matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/186959/correlation-matrix-from-covariance-matrix)