# Why the covariance matrix of a matrix is the product $XX'$

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics, self-learning, covariance

> Let a matrix of random observations such that
>   $$\textbf{X}=\begin{bmatrix}x_{11}&x_{12}\\ x_{21}&
>  x_{22}\end{bmatrix}$$
>   where $x_{jk}$ is the jth measure of the kth variable.Each column is a random variable. Why the covariance matrix of $\textbf{X}$ is
>   given by $XX'$?

I don't understood this result, because

$$\overline{x}_k=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n x_{ik}$$

in this case $\overline{x_1}=\frac{x_{11}+x_{21}}{2}$ and $\overline{x_2}=\frac{x_{12}+x_{22}}{2}$

and the sample covariances are given by
$$s_{ik}=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^n(x_{ji}-\overline{x_i})(x_{jk}-\overline{x_k})$$

Taking $s_{11}$ as example

$$s_{11}=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{j=1}^2 (x_{j1}-\overline{x_1})^2=\frac{1}{2}\Big((x_{11}-(\frac{x_{11}+x_{21}}{2}))^2+(x_{21}-(\frac{x_{11}+x_{21}}{2}   ))^2\Big)$$
$$=\frac{x_{11}^2}{2}-x_{11}x_{21}+\frac{x_{21}^2}{2}$$

If I make $$XX'$$ then $$s_{11}=x_{11}^2+x_{21}^2$$

I made some confusion? Or is there some restriction to this result?

**EDIT:** I get this result from here [Correlation matrix from Covariance matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/186959/correlation-matrix-from-covariance-matrix) . Since no one said that is wrong I assumed that will be valid in this case too.

Comment: It's not clear what your data matrix $X$ even represents. Are independent observations organized by row? Also, the covariance matrix is often written $X'X$ (or $XX'$, depending on how you organize your matrix $X$) where $X$ is a "column-centered" (i.e, mean zero) version of the data. So to address your question, you should probably think about $(X-\bar{x})'(X - \bar{x})$ where $\bar{x} = (\bar{x}_1 1_n, \bar{x}_2 1_n)$ where $1_n$ is the $n-$vector of ones.

Comment: The statement is incorrect. If the rows of $X$ form the samples, the covariance matrix is $XX'/n$ (where $n$ is the number of samples), but only if the mean is zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is indeed a restriction of the result: this formula is only correct if each row has mean $0$.  See this explained, for example, on the [wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_matrix).  The same seems to be true for [correlation matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlation_and_dependence#Correlation_matrices).

Presumably, one takes the rows of the observation matrix to have mean zero "by default".