# Calculate correlation matrix from covariance matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, statistics

I need to find the correlation matrix from a covariance matrix. The covariance matrix is the following: $$\frac{1}{4} \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0.1 \\ 0.1 & 2  \end{pmatrix}$$

I've read [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/186959/correlation-matrix-from-covariance-matrix) but I still can't get how for $a_{ij}$ in the correlation matrix $a_{ij} = \frac{\sigma_{ij}}{\sigma_i \sigma_j}$. How do we get a single $\sigma_i$ or $\sigma_j$? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\sigma_{ii}$ is the covariance of the $i$-th component with itself, and if you inspect the definition of covariance, you'll see that it is actually equal to the variance of the $i$-th component. $\sigma_i$ is its standard deviation, hence $\sigma_i=\sqrt{\sigma_{ii}}$. So in your matrix, $\sigma_1 = \sqrt{\frac14\cdot 1} =\frac12$ and $\sigma_2 = \sqrt{\frac14\cdot 2} =\frac1{\sqrt2}$.

Comment: Thanks a lot, so in the example, the correlation matrix would be $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0.07 \\ 0.07 & 1  \end{pmatrix}$?

Comment: Yes, $\frac{\frac{0.1}{4}}{\frac12\cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt2}}\approx 0.07$.